# Expected Value - wrong reasoning, right answer?

Tags: probability

If we have sequences of random numbers between 1 and 64 (and all numbers are equally likely), what would be the expected length of numbers in a sequence before we get a 1,2 or 3?

My reasoning was as follows.

The probability of separate events means that we can add up the individual probabilities.  The probability of getting a 1,2, or 3 is 3/64.   Thus if we had sequence with two random numbers and we wanted to find out the probability of the first one or the second one being a 1,2, or 3, we would add the individual probabilities (3/64) + (3/64).

It seems to me that we want to calculate how many numbers in a sequence it takes before we reach probability = 1, so we can simply write out a formula as follows
1= (3/64) + (3/64) + (3/64) ...
or
1 = (3/64) * n
 and thus solve for n
n = 21.3334
Thus we can conclude that on average, every 21.3334 numbers will contain a 1,2, or 3.

I believe this value to be correct, however I have reason to believe that my reasoning is rather flawed.  I do not think in retrospect that I should be adding the probabilities of the random numbers up like that, however I am at a loss to explain why my answer appears to fit the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result and the calculation $\frac{1}{\frac{3}{64}}=\frac{64}{3}=21.6666...$ both
 are correct.

The addition of the $\frac{3}{64}$-terms would only be correct, if the value would be 
 an integer, and even then it is not intuitively clear, why the result should be $1$.

So, you better take the formula for the first sucess :

$$p_n=(1-p)^{n-1}p$$

The expected value is then

$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty p_jj=p\sum_{j=1}^\infty j(1-p)^{j-1}=p\sum_{j=0}^\infty (j+1)(1-p)^j=p\frac{1-p}{p^2}+1=\frac{1-p}{p}+1=\frac{1}{p}$$

Comment: I appreciate your confirmation of my answer and explanation of the correct way to arrive at the answer.  I wonder however if you might be able to explain a little bit more about the math of your answer. 
1) I have never seen the "first success" formula, where does this come from?
2) I am not following your simplification of the sum to 1/p.
- why can you move the p outside of the sum in the first step?
- how did you go from j(1-p)^j-1 to (j+1)(1-p)^j?  
- and then where did all the j's go in the next simplification?
- how did you simplify ((1-p)/p) + 1 to 1/p
I apologize for my lack of math...

Comment: The formula for $p_n$ is easy to explain : If try number $n$ is the first sucess, we must have $n-1$ consecutive failures followed by a success.

Comment: The simplification of the series follows from $$\sum_{j=0}^\infty jx^j=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$ and $$\sum_{j=0}^\infty x^j=\frac{1}{1-x}$$

Comment: $\frac{1-p}{p}+1=\frac{1-p}{p}+\frac{p}{p}=\frac{1-p+p}{p}=\frac{1}{p}$

Comment: $p$ is constant, so it can be brought in front of the sum.

Comment: Thank you for your further explanations.  The formula for pn does indeed make sense now.  I do not understand the simplification of the series or the step which goes from a sum into just a regular formula, but I will try to find other sources in which I can learn this type of math.  Any suggestions you have on a resource would be helpful though.

Answer (score 0):

> I believe this value to be correct, however I have reason to believe that my reasoning is rather flawed.  I do not think in retrospect that I should be adding the probabilities of the random numbers up like that, however I am at a loss to explain why my answer appears to fit the solution.

Correct, your reasoning is flawed.

> Thus if we had sequence with two random numbers and we wanted to find out the probability of the first one or the second one being a 1,2, or 3, we would add the individual probabilities (3/64) + (3/64).

You forgot to exclude the probability that the first **and** second result is a success (ie: being one of the numbers we want).  Remember the **Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion**?

In any case, what you *want* to do is to measure the probability of *not* encountering those number *until* a certain draw.   That gives the probability of running a certain length of trials.   So, for example, the probability of not encountering 1,2, or 3 until the second draw is: $\dfrac{61}{64}\dfrac{3}{64}$.  That is, the probability of having one failure before a success on the second draw.

In general, the probability of all failures before a success on trial $n$ with trial success probability $p$ is:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(N=n) & = (1-p)^{n-1}p \\ & =\dfrac{61^{n-1} 3}{64^n} & \impliedby p=\frac 3{64}
\end{align}$$

Then you apply the definition of expectation.  $$\begin{align}
\mathsf E[N] & = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n\,\mathsf P(N=n)
\\ & = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n(1-p)^{n-1} p
\\ & = \frac 1 p & \impliedby \text{re: geometric series}
\\ & = 21\, \tfrac 1 3
\end{align}$$